# Calendar DVWP to show only today with recurring and all day events

Tags: data-view-web-part, calendar, filter, date-time

I got a interesting problem here.  I developed a dashboard for one of our departments, they wanted a widget that shows only today's events.  I have the DVWP in place, and filtering by a calculated column, which also shows all day events.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to show events that span across a whole week(i.e. PTO for a week).  I want that persons PTO to show up everyday, not just the first day it occurs.  The example below shows the PTO for today, and the re-occuring birthday because this is the day the event starts on.

I am currently filtering for (calculated column for start date) = (currentDate).  Any thoughts?!?!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Events have end DateTimes also.  So try the following date logic instead:

```
calculated_col_for_start <= today and calculated_col_for_end >= today
```

See if that capture all day events that span more than one day, like the PTO event.

Comment: And that works great for normal items, but for recurring items it doesn't pick them up.

Comment: Oops - yeah mine just solves the ones 'that span across a whole week'.  If my solution does not work, perhaps the time component is throwing off the first day of the spanning event.  In your calculated start and end column, you could truncate the time part off of the Start and End, that might help you.